# Check if div has Elements and does not have certain Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I already had a similar thread opened except the condition that the div does not have a second Element in it.
So my last Question was this:

I have some Code which looks like this

```
<p class="elementWrap">
  <label>Phone</label>
  <input class="form_elem" type="text" name="form_phone">
  <span class="form_required">*</span>
</p>
```

and sometimes like this

```
<p class="elementWrap">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input class="form_elem" type="text" name="form_name">
</p>
```

[rgraham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571194/rgraham) posted this solution which works fine

```
$(".elementWrap").filter(function() {
    return $(this).children(".form_required").length;
}).find("label").css({'width':'auto','margin':'0px'});
```

But now I dont want to apply this code on Labels which have Inputs with the type Radio.
I thought about something like return the length of children .form_required and not input type radio. But dont know how to write this as code. =/

Comment: See please my Last UPDATE . it is useful & less coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".elementWrap").filter(function() {
    var has_required = $(this).children(".form_required").length > 0,
        no_radio    = $(this).find(':radio').length < 1;

    return has_required && no_radio;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Jquery Docs:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>has demo</title>
    <style>
        .full {
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li>Does the UL contain an LI?</li>
</ul>
<script>
    $("ul").append("<li>" +
        ( $("ul").has("li").length ? "Yes" : "No" ) +
        "</li>");
    $("ul").has("li").addClass("full");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

http://api.jquery.com/has/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".elementWrap:has(.form_required)").filter($(".elementWrap:not(:has(:radio))"))
```

Known that `$one.filter($two)` ≅ `$one  ∩ $two`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/6CVmC/1/)